# Question on Hamming codes

Tags: coding-theory

Maybe I am the one who is not thinking clearly but I think there is a typo in  a question from  [Introduction to Error Correcting Codes with Applications by Scott A. Vanstone](https://books.google.ca/books/about/An_Introduction_to_Error_Correcting_Code.html?id=YKFKbXaSmnYC). Its question 5 on page 96 which asks the following:

Question: What is the smallest integer n for which a single-error correcting binary linear code of block length $n$ carrying  $62$ bits of information per codeword can be constructed.

As this is a single error correcting code, then it is clearly a [Hamming code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) since the minimum distance of the code is 3. I think the question should be to determine the smallest number $r$. Clearly $n=62$ so I don't see why this was asked again. And by calculation the smallest value  of $r$ is $6$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the suggestion $r=6$ is that the Hamming code of length $2^6-1=63$ has six check bits and hence a single block carries only $63-6=57$ bits of information.

Meaning that you really need $r=7$. For the price of seven check bits you can go up to blocks carrying $(2^7-1)-7=120$ bits worth of information using a longer Hamming code. Provided that in your application this does not uncomfortably increase the risk of there being two bit errors within a block.

Comment: Oh I see what I am supposed to do. The question is correct and I think what I need to solve is $n+1=2^{n-62}$ or equivalently $63=2^r-r$. Thanks

Comment: @Jaynot Slightly more precisely: You need to find the smallest integer $n$ such that $n-r= 62$, and $n\le 2^r-1$ for some positive integer $r$.

Comment: I think the smallest value of $n$ is 69. Right?

Comment: Correct, @Jaynot.

Comment: Can I please ask you a different question on Plotkin bound for binary codes? or should I just post it as a new question

Comment: Better ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks. I just did